# Django conditionally count annotated values in "group-by" statement

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Having the following models:

```
class TheModel(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)


class Item(models.Model):
    the_model = models.ForeignKey(TheModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='items')
```

How can be calculated the number of models and how many of them have more than 2 items grouped by day?
I tried:

```
qs = models.TheModel.objects.all()
qs = qs.annotate(contained_items=Count('items'))
result = qs.values('created_at__date').annotate(
    total_count=Count('created_at__date'),
    models_with_contained_items=Count('created_at__date', filter=Q(contained_items__gt=2))
)
```

But it raises "OperationalError" "misuse of aggregate function COUNT()"

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractDay, ExtractMonth, ExtractYear

query_set = Model.objects.filter(contained_items__gt=2).annotate(day=ExtractDay('created_at'), month=ExtractMonth('created_at'), year=ExtractYear('created_at')).values('day', 'month', 'year').annotate(total_count=Count('items')).values('day', 'month', 'year', 'total_count').order_by()
```

Read more about [Extract](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/database-functions/#extract)

A question might arise, why order_by() is used at last? It is used because at the end Django always applies its default ordering so you might get unexpected results and not get the data grouped, so to overcome that .order_by() is used without any parameters to tell django to not apply any ordering at the end.